# PyQt Not updating label

Tags: python, pyqt

I've created a simple application to transfer files using Paramiko and SFTP. I also wanted to have a statusbar (a QLabel) to inform the user when I'm downloading/uploading stuff. So, my function to upload looks something like this:

```
def upload(self):
        self.statusLabel.setText('Uploading')
        local = str(self.uploadLineEdit.text())
        filename = os.path.basename(local)
        remote = "/home/" + self.userName + "/testdata/" + filename
        self.ftp.put(local, remote)
        self.uploadedFileName = filename
        self.statusLabel.setText('Upload Finished')
```

Notice that before starting the upload I change the statusbar to uploading, and when upload is done, I change it to upload finished.

However, what actually happens is that the "Uploading" message is never displayed on the label - it just goes straight to "Upload Finished". I suspect this is because the changes happen only after the function returns.

How do I get the label to change at the start of the upload process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might need to force processing of events after changing the label text. Try adding:

```
QApplication.processEvents()
```

after setting the label text.

Please note that for a reason not known to me, PyQt and PySide both tend to have problems with `processEvents`, which sometimes needs to be executed multiple times to take effect. So, if it does not work after adding a single `processEvents()`, try adding it twice, or even multiple times.

Comment: this work, +1 for mentioning that I might have to do it multiple times.

Comment: Glad to help, go ahead and accept the answer then :)

Comment: There seems to be a time limit so I can't accept it right now, but will as soon as I'm able to.

Comment: True, I'm all new to that myself.